# Access Fiware objectstorage from Ruby: how do I connect without using password

Tags: ruby, fiware, openstack-swift

I have an ruby-on-rails app which should store and retrieve images from Fiware objectstorage (which is based on Openstack swift).
There is gem called [ruby-openstack](https://github.com/ruby-openstack/ruby-openstack) that semm to do everything I need.

It works when I hardcode my email and fiware-password. But this seem not to be the right thing to do. The connection method gives me two other options:

```
# :auth_method - Type of authentication - 'password', 'key', 'rax-kskey' - defaults to 'password'"
# :username - Your OpenStack username or public key, depending on auth_method. *required*
# :api_key - Your OpenStack API key *required* (either private key or password, depending on auth_method)
```

Should I choose "key" or "rax-kskey", and where do I get these keys from?
Is the private key the same I use to log in via ssh? 
Or has it something to do with the "app" I can create in the Fiware-Backend?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.
For more specificity check the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ruby-openstack/ruby-openstack)

> :auth_method - the type of authentication to be used with the above auth_url - either 'password' (username/password, 'key' (ec2 style key/private key) or 'rax-kskey'.

```
OpenStack::Connection.create({:username => "AWHFDADHJ32EL6V23GFK", :api_key=>"jd823jFDJEY2/82jfhYteG52AKJAUEY184JHRfeR", :auth_method=> "key", :auth_url => "https://regionerer-g.go-bar.identity.dacloudfoo.herpy:13327/v2.0/", :authtenant_id =>"482195756462871", :service_type=>"object-store"})
```

The Key location is at OpenStack administration panel. Settings -> OpenStuck Api -> EC2

Comment: The exact example does not work: "can't connect to server. ". But I had not expected to see a valid key there....

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see "Settings -> Openstack Api". Probably because this is "FIWARE", and they have wrapped the original Openstack to give accounts to normal developers, And I'm such a developer and not an administrator, so I probably have not access to some options in the backend.